# Maven equivalent of SBT "test->test"

Tags: maven, sbt

I would like to use some classes defined in the test section of a Maven project for tests of *another* project that depends on it. The classes are more testing-related utilities than actual tests. This is achieved in SBT by using the notation `test->test` when declaring the dependency.

Is there a Maven equivalent for this? Does the solution work with IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't do that in Maven.

You write an additional project/module that contains the testing-related utilities.